# vb .net custom component icon

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I add a icon to my custom component, to be displayed on toolbox?
I have component designed in vb, should I make some dll or activex first? (I preffer not since I'm still developping)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Use the `<ToolboxBitmap>` attribute.  It is a bit troublesome, nobody that uses your code is going to care that the bitmap look right.  Write code for your family members and friends first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 // [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(TextBox))]  // set default icons
    [ToolboxBitmap(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Joe\MyPics\myImage.bmp")]  // set own icons
```

EXAMPLE override textbox :

```
private bool IsNum = true;

[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(TextBox))] 
        [PropertyTab("IsNumaric")]
        [DisplayName("IsNumaricTextBox")]
        [Category("EmsoftBehaviors")]
        [Description("If this is 'True' then textbox accept only numbers")]
        public bool IsNumaricTextBox
        {
            set
            {
                IsNum = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return IsNum;
            }
        }
```